TQDM: Track loop inside ProcessPoolExecutor job
I have some number of jobs that have been submitted to a ProcessPoolExecutor. I want to track the progress of each job with tqdm. However, when I run the code below, the progress bars constantly swap places. I believe this is because *handwavey asynchronicity explanation* but I don't know the method to get around that. I imagine I could theoretically pipeline the progress bar up to the parent process, but I'm not familiar enough with concurrent or tqdm to do that. What's the pythonic answer?
MWE:
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
import concurrent
import random
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def main():
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    futures = [pool.submit(my_function,x) for x in range(10)]
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        print(future)

def my_function(fn_number):
    for i in tqdm(range(500),desc=f"{fn_number}_outer"):
        for j in tqdm(range(500),desc=f"{fn_number}_inner"):
            # Sometimes the function skips to the outer loop.
            # This is foiling using tqdm.update()
            if random()>0.9:
                break
            sleep(0.1)
    return fn_number

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()


Could you use process_map to do this? This is a tdqm function which combines multiple processes and a progress bar. https://tqdm.github.io/docs/contrib.concurrent/#process_map

I can't convert my_function into something that operates on an iterable. In-context, it's a big mess of selenium code that returns a result, and I'm just using parallelization to reduce runtime. That's also why I'm hooking tqdm to the loops inside my_function: Seeing the progress of each call of my_function is more useful to the user than seeing the percent of my_functions that have completed

Got it. What about a using a package like tqdm-multiprocess to send the progress information back from each subprocess to the main process?
